# C++: No breakpoints work

Tags: c++, debugging, gcc, gdb

This is probably a very basic question. However, I couldn't find any answer by searching the web.

I have a code I need to debug written in C++. For this code, I require to use GCC 4.1.2 in compatibility reasons and I am using GDB 6.6-45. I compiled the code with the `-g -Wall -O0` flags to make sure the code can be debugged with GDB.

My problem is that wherever I set the breakpoint, no breakpoints get hit. Also, at the end of the run, I get this message "You can't do that without a process to debug".

By the sound of the message, I think I am missing a very trivial thing. However, I cannot figure out.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**:

The platform I am working on is Fedora 8 on VirtualBox. The reason why I am working on VirtualBox is because I wasn't good enough to install older version of GCC (4.1.2) properly without breaking Fedora 20, which is the latest.

As per GDB output, (it's very basic):

```
[localhost]$ gdb programName
GNU gdb Red Hat Linux (6.6-45.fc8rh)
... typical messages
This GDB was configured as "i386-redhat-linux-gnu"...
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/libthread_db.so.1".
(gdb) run programName (program arguments here)
...
Program outputs and messages
...

Program exited normally.
You can't do that without a process to debug.
(gdb)
```

What's shown above is all I have. To set my breakpoints, I did something similar to:

```
break main
break System::function_name
break System::line_number
```

and when I run `info breakpoints`, the breakpoints does show correct cpp file and the line number or the function name, with enabled flag to yes.

Comment: Knowing the platform you are on may be helpful to those providing answers.

Comment: Show the output of your gdb session.

Comment: Ah, okay. I'll edit. I wasn't sure how I should ask this question.

Comment: How are you setting the breakpoints?

Comment: From your shell on your Virtual Box, type `echo $SHELL`, and check if the file it gives you actually exists.

Comment: I am not sure what I am expected to see, but the output points to `/bin/bash` and the bash file does exist.

Comment: Apart from function/method based break points, have you tried with file line number based break points?

Comment: Yes, I have and the result is the same.

Comment: Where are you setting the breakpoints?

Comment: I have set them to many different places, from main function to random lines in different files. None of them seem to work.

Comment: Try setting breakpoints with `__asm__("int 3");`. (Type it in the code where you want the breakpoint.) If it doesn't work, then gdb isn't attaching to your process correctly and you may have to install an old gdb as well. Google int3 for more info.

Answer (score 0):

If possible try to avoid -O flag and just use -g -Wall only. I have seen some problems with -O flag in older versions. But I'm not sure whether they persist in novel gcc as well. Just give it a try.

Comment: Actually, I didn't have `-O` flag initially. As an attempt to solve the problem, I added the flag. The results are the same.